# How to math exact digits if the surroundings are digits?

Tags: grep

```
cat x.txt 
62643383279533330288419716

grep 333 x.txt 
62643383279533330288419716

grep 3333 x.txt 
62643383279533330288419716

grep -w 333 x.txt 

grep -w 3333 x.txt
```

How to grep for only "333"? If I use plain "grep 333 x.txt" it will output the 3333 too!

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? To a) not print the line because it doesn't contain a sequence `333` not surrounded by other `3`s, b) print only `333` if any line contains `333`, or c) something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the precise pattern you are looking for, use `-o`:

```
$ grep -o 333 x.txt
333
```

Comment: `eee` cannot match 333.

Comment: It must be Tuesday.  I never could get the hang of Tuesdays.